# assign function to packetbuf_copyfrom

Tags: c, contiki

I want to assign function to `packetbuf_copyfrom()`. I used `*` and `&` but it doesn't give me the right cipher after it shifts it.

This is the function:

```
void caesar (char cipher[], int shift) {
    int i = 0;
    while (cipher[i] != '\0') {
        cipher[i] += (shift);
        i++;
    }
    printf("%s\n", cipher);
}

{
  char cipher[10]="Hello";
    int key = 5;
    caesar (cipher, key);   
    packetbuf_copyfrom((*caesar),8);

}
```

I want the `packet_copyfrom()` function to copy from function `caesar`.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

First, Caesar cipher formula is

[image]

So your code could be:

```
cipher[i] = (cipher[i] - 'a' + shift)%26 + 'a'; // for input is lower case and output is lower case.
```

Second, you should consider the character case when you apply the formula. You want all upper case or lower case? Just make sure your encoding and decoding consistent.

Third, passing `cipher` to `packetbuf_copyfrom`

```
packetbuf_copyfrom(&cipher[0],8);
```

Comment: Your encipherment fragment only works on lower-case letters sensibly; for upper-case letters and (more particularly) non-letters, it produces ... incorrect output.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, indeed, I did mention in the code comments and in the `Second` statement.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you could do is provide a little more context for your question.  However, Google's search rides to the rescue: you can find documentation for [`packetbuf_copyfrom()`](http://contiki.sourceforge.net/docs/2.6/a01687.html) online.

The signature of the function is:

```
int packetbuf_copyfrom(const void *from, uint16_t len)
```

> *Copy from external data into the packetbuf.*

Given that your `caesar()` function does the shift in place, you need to invoke:

```
packet_copyfrom(cipher, 6);
```

This should copy the 5 shifted characters and a trailing null to your packetbuf.  If you only want the 5 characters, change 6 to 5.

You should probably review your `caesar()` function; it shifts all characters, including the null byte, by `shift` positions.  This is a possible design decision, but it is not a usual one.  Some character will be mapped to a null byte (that with character code 125, usually `'{'`).  Be careful.

Comment: i did packet_copyfrom(cipher, 6); but it doesn't work , the Q is could i assign a function to packet_copyfrom(,); ??

Comment: The question does not make sense (to me). I don't understand what the notation `packet_copyfrom(,);` means.  If you mean 'can I use a pointer to function to copy data to the right place?' then the answer is 'yes, provided that the interface matches or you create a function so that the interface matches'.  If you mean something else, please explain. I'm also not clear where you want to use the pointer to function. I do understand that English is probably not your first language, but I'm not able to understand what you mean. Is packet_copyfrom() supposed to replace the `printf()`, perhaps?